# Excel formula to sum a column if there are duplicated in one column and if there is specific text in another column

Tags: excel-formula, powerquery

I could use some guidance on what an excel formula would look like if I wanted to sum values in one column if duplicated cells exist in another column as well as specific text in another column. In the example below, I want to sum Column C if Column A has duplicated cells and Column B has the text "Income" and "Special Cash."

```
       Column A        Column B            Column C
Row 1) BGIO US Equity   Income               0.05
Row 2) BGIO US Equity   Short Term Cap Gain  0.009573
Row 3) BGIO US Equity   Special Cash         0.00931
```

I would also like to concatenate Column B if the rates are summed. In the end, I am hoping to end up with the results below where Row 1 and Row 2 meet these criteria:

```
       Column A         Column B                Column C
Row 1) BGIO US Equity   Income + Special Cash    0.05931
Row 2) BGIO US Equity   Short Term Cap Gain      0.009573
```

Any feedback is very much appreciated!

Comment: Try using a `SUMIFS` formula.

Comment: Can you incorporate all of the above criteria in a SUMIFS formula? If so, what would the formula look like?

Comment: No, for the concatenation you need something else. Is there a reason you want to end up with duplicate rows?

Comment: My reasoning is so that I can remove duplicates when all is said and done, but it is not necessary.

Comment: if you it is easier to do this with VBA, then I am open for that as well

Comment: This is pretty simple with Power Query. Is that OK?

Comment: Yes, Power Query is OK

Answer (score 0):

If you have your data in a table, you can load it into the Power Query editor by clicking on the table and choosing From Table under the Data tab.

[image: From Table]

Create a custom column that you will group by. (Custom Column under Add Column tab.)

[image: Custom Column]

Now Group By (Home tab) `Deal` and `Group` and aggregate over `Amount`.

[image: Group By]

This should be the result set that you want. You can now Close and Load the transformed table into your workbook.

Comment: Thanks Alexis. I'll let you know how this works out.

Comment: Hi Alexis - In order to get the permissions I need to download power query to my work computer I have to get it approved from corporate. So i'm stuck for the time being, unless you can direct me on what this would look like using VBA.